# HTML: search onblur onfocus defaultvalue and onsubmit

Tags: html, search, onblur, onsubmit, onfocus

im trying to build a search box with a default value "Search Here" for example, onfocus it will clear it, and onblur if its empty it will bring back "Search Here".

for this i can use:

```
onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value = ''";
onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue";
```

this works just fine, but when i hit search without inputing a text, it searchs for "Search Here".

what is the best way of removing the default value before searching?

Comment: Do you want users to be able to search for blank values?

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML5 placeholder attribute. Like so:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search here"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a user to be able to search for and empty search query, you can just catch the default search string on the back-end (php/asp/whatever) and replace it with an empty string.

Or you can use javascript to prevent the submit if the defaultvalue is in the searchbox if you want to prevent the search.

Comment: Yep, compare the this.value against "Search Here" string directly instead of this.defaultValue, then clear it if there is a match.